# String variables order

Tags: c++, string, variables

I'm currently learning through Bjarne Stroustrup's book "Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++".

I'm at the point where we try to concatenate strings using the following example (edited for the actual code as requested):

I apologize I failed to mention that the program works. But whenever I type both names it shows blank.

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()

{

string first;
string second;
string name = first + ' ' + second;


cout << "Please enter your first and second names\n";
cin >> first >> second;
cout << "Hello, "<<name<<'\n';


}
```

I just want to mention that this is not the way it was written in the book. I just wanted to play with different setups such as putting all the string variables in one area together. However, I found out that `String name = first + ' ' +second;` does not work unless I put it after the `cin >> first >> second;` line.
Is there an explanation for this?

Reference code from the book:

```
int main ()
{

cout<<"Please enter your first and second name\n";
string first;
string second;
cin>>first>>second;
string name=first +' '+second;
cout<< Hello, "<<name<<'\n';
}
```

Comment: Please show the actual code that caused the problem instead of the comment along with the error.

Comment: You're concatenating the empty strings before taking input so the `name` would be empty when you print it. The statements are executed in sequential order. You can declare the variables first and then use them later. Example: https://godbolt.org/z/VshbWX

Comment: I fixed it, sorry about that.

Comment: Thank you! I was worried that I would have to declare the variable name after the input. Your example showed otherwise.

Comment: That is a good practice to create variables where they're needed. You keep the declaration and initialization in one place and you can achieve const-correctness also. You'll learn about these things as you progress futher. Good luck!

Comment: You could make a lambda `auto name=[=]{return first +' '+second;};` and evaluate it at the correct point in code: `cout<< Hello, "<<name()<<'\n';`. This would make it possible to write your rule for calculating `name` before the user entered the data. Looks pointless for such a simple example, but it's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I mean it probably did work. The problem here is that the result isn't what you think it is.

Strings are usually empty by default. So an empty string + a space + another empty string = just a space. It's highly likely you're seeing this space, but it looks empty because spaces are, well, spaces.

If you want to concatenate the input from the user, you will have to do so **after** you capture that input as the program has no other way to know what the user inputted otherwise.

If you're still confused, I'm afraid I unfortunately don't know what else to tell you other than that's just the way C++ works.

Comment: You are right, the program did work and it showed an empty space after I input the names. It makes sense now that it only works after it captures the input. Thank you so much for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking more into what a variable is and what cin does. A variable holds a value. cin retrieves input from a user and puts it into a variable. Of course adding two variables with no value will not work as if there were values there. Instead, you are adding two blank strings to a space.

Also, when you do:

```
string name=first +' '+second;
```

You are setting name to the value of first plus the value of ' ' plus the value of second. The variable is *not* a reference to those values. Meaning that changing first and second after this point does not affect the value of the 'name' variable.

Comment: I will look further into those topics. Thank you for the clarification.